# CKAN: How do I specify the encoding of my resource file?

Tags: api, character-encoding, ckan

I'm publishing my CSV files to CKAN using the API. I want to make my data easy to open in Brazilian Excel, so it must have:

1. semicolon ";" separated columns
2. coma "," as a decimal separator
3. use encoding cp-1252

I'm using Data Store and Data Pusher.

My problem is that if I upload my data with encoding cp1252, Data Pusher sends it as is to the Data Store that expects the data as UTF-8. The data preview doesn't display the accents correctly. In the image below `Março` were the correct value to display:

[image: Should have been Março]

I want to have my user downloading the data as cp-1252, so it opens easily in Excel, but also have CKAN displaying it correctly. I must specify the encoding of the file while uploading the file.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't specify the encoding directly, but taking a look at Data Pusher source I saw that it uses the Messy Tables library. MT obey the environment locale set of the host machine, so I configure it to `pt_BR.UTF8` and my accents worked fine.

Now I can publish my data with commas as a decimal separator and using encoding Windows-1252. The data correctly opens in Excel when it is downloaded, and is also correctly displayed in the Data Explorer.